# How to make Django generic views accessible to logged in users only?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I've implemented the social-auth for Google for users to log in. I cannot understand how to restrict the visitors from accessing the generic views like UpdateView, ListView or CreateView, if they are not logged in with the social-auth system. Here is the code.

***views.py***

```
class AchievementCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = AchievementForm2
    model = Achievements
    def form_valid(self, form):
            achieves = form.save(commit=False)
            achieves.resume = Resume.objects.get(pk=2)
            return super(AchievementCreate, self).form_valid(form)

def home(request):
#logout(request)
    uname=""
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'submit' in request.POST:
        submit = request.POST['submit']
        if submit=="sign-out":
            logout(request)

    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        uname=sm.UserSocialAuth.objects.get(
        user_id=int(request.session['_auth_user_id'])
        ).user
        request.session['uname']=str(uname)
    return render(request,'cv/home.html',{'uname': uname})
```

***home.html***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'cv:home' %}">{% csrf_token %}
            {% if uname %}
                Helo, {{uname}}<br>
                The user already signed in. He may need to sign out<br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign-out">            
            {% else %}
                Please sign-in<br>
                <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Google login</a>
            {% endif %}  
        </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^achievements/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AchievementDelete.as_view(), name='achievement-delete'),
url(r'^achievements/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AchievementUpdate.as_view(), name='achievement-update'),
url(r'^achievements/add/$', login_required(views.AchievementCreate.as_view()), name='achievement-add'),
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),]
```

I want the "AchievementCreate" class to be accessible only if the user has logged in. But I don't understand how. Is it possible to use sessions? How, in this case?

Comment: The `login_required` decorator is not working?

Comment: Nope. It isn't.

Answer (score 2):

We need to write mixins to check whether the user is logged in or not.

Django 1.9 has introduced a LoginRequiredMixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
```

The following code is a custom mixin, which will check user is active or inactive. If the user is inactive, it will logout the session. We need to write mixins in a separate file like mixins.py, import the mixins in views

```
class UserMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                return super(UserMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                logout(self.request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cv:home'))
```

In Views.py

```
from mixins.py import UserMixin 

class UserEdit(UserMixin, View):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = "dashboard/edit_user.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the login_required decorator and put @login_reqired infront of the view. This view will than only be accesable when logged in.

Example:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    @login_required
    #put your view here
```

Comment: Did you use it in your views.py or just in front of the view in the url.py?

Comment: I used this and it worked.  @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AchievementCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Is there any way to access "request.session['uname']" inside a generic view class?

Comment: I use the auth_user model from django and all i need to call is `request.user.<attribute>`

Comment: I'm getting "global name 'request' is not defined" when I try that.

Comment: @DoucheTholi: the CBV's 'entry points' (`dispatch`, `get`, `post` etc) methods take the request as first argument (well second - the first argument being 'self'). If you want to access the request in another method of the CBV, you have to use `self.request` instead.

Comment: Note, that this only works for function-based views, not class-based ones. Use MicroPyramid's answer for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using 'social-auth' for your login system. In your case, you will have to use a custom function. I'm assuming you can access the logged in user by referring to:
`request.SESSION`

If so, then you can override the dispatch method of your CreateView:

```
class AchievementCreate(CreateView):
   .....
   .....
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      user = request.session['_auth_user_id']
      # handle authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Do something for authenticated users

    else:
        # Do something for anonymous users
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests